# how to split a duration by hourly basis depending on start and end time in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How can I split a duration by one hour interval depending on the start time and end time?

Like, if start time = 6:30:00 and end time = 8:30:00 then from 6.30 to 7.30 it will give h1, 7.30 to 8.30 it will give h2 n all.. Tried with dense_rank but didn't work.. Can anyone plz help?

[image: data reference]

I need to have hour_of_shift h1,h2... like this..with time key 0630 to 0730 it will give h1 and so on..
tried with this query

```
select td.time_key tdkey, shft.shid shid,
 ('h' || DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY substr(time_key, 1, 2))) hour_of_shift
from smartweld_sample_dev4.time_dim td, 
     smartweld_sample_dev4.shift shft 
where td.timeofday::time between shft.START and shft.END;
```

but it is giving h1 for 6.30 to 7.00 and then it is increasing the rank by one.how can can do that?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Also: sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. It would also help if you add an example of the output you want (as formatted text, not a screen shot)

Comment: Why not join shift data subselect like `select 'sh'||shift_hour_no, '07:30'::time + shift_hour_no * (interval '1 hour') as from,'07:30'::time + (shift_hour_no + 1) * (interval '1 hour') as till
FROM generate_series(0, 7 /* hours in the shift */) as shift_hour_no` ??

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis this helped me alot..this is done.thank u so much.